# 90% query time elapsed in sorting dataset

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am executing a query

```
select
    "master_date"."date_id" as "c0", 
    "npa"."npa" as "c1", 
    "nxx"."nxx" as "c2"
from 
    "public"."master_date" as "master_date", 
    "public"."agg_npanxx_traffic_daily" as "agg_npanxx_traffic_daily", 
    "public"."npa" as "npa", 
    "public"."nxx" as "nxx" 
where 
    "agg_npanxx_traffic_daily"."record_date" = "master_date"."date_id" 
    and "agg_npanxx_traffic_daily"."id_npa" = "npa"."id_npa" 
    and "agg_npanxx_traffic_daily"."id_nxx" = "nxx"."id_nxx" 
    and ("master_date"."date_id" in (
        '2015-05-03', '2015-05-04', '2015-05-05', 
        '2015-05-06', '2015-05-07', '2015-05-08', '2015-05-09')
    ) 
group by 
    "master_date"."date_id", 
    "npa"."npa", "nxx"."nxx" 
order by 
    "master_date"."date_id" ASC NULLS LAST, 
    "npa"."npa" ASC NULLS LAST, 
    "nxx"."nxx" ASC NULLS LAST
```

It takes 420 seconds to execute and 90% of time is elapsed in sorting. Here is the execution plan : http://explain.depesz.com/s/659D.

I have configured `work_mem` as 2048 MB.

I want to optimize this and decrease query time.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't use external links for important information - add the *minimal necessary* information in your question (by using the "edit" button).

Comment: Format the query better, it's unreadable right now. And use table aliases!

Comment: You probably need to split all that in a couple of sorted subqueries with a composed index for each group by and order column

Comment: just create indexex for the required fields. Or create views that can give you o/p faster.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
SELECT   "master_date"."date_id"             AS "c0", 
         "npa"."npa"                         AS "c1", 
         "nxx"."nxx"                         AS "c2" 
FROM     "public"."master_date" AS "master_date", 
          CROSS JOIN "public"."npa" AS "npa", 
          CROSS JOIN "public"."nxx" AS "nxx" 
WHERE     "master_date"."date_id" IN ( '2015-05-03', 
                                       '2015-05-04', 
                                       '2015-05-05', 
                                       '2015-05-06', 
                                       '2015-05-07', 
                                       '2015-05-08', 
                                       '2015-05-09')
           AND EXISTS(
             SELECT *   
                FROM "public"."agg_npanxx_traffic_daily" as "agg_npanxx_traffic_daily"
                WHERE
                  "agg_npanxx_traffic_daily"."id_npa" = "npa"."id_npa" 
                  AND "agg_npanxx_traffic_daily"."id_nxx" = "nxx"."id_nxx" 
            )
ORDER BY "master_date"."date_id" ASC nulls last, 
         "npa"."npa" ASC nulls last, 
         "nxx"."nxx" ASC nulls last
```